# Magento extension is not working properly on production server

Tags: magento-1.8, extensions

I'm trying to install this extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/postcode-nl-postcode-complementation-and-validation.html but it's not working.

I can see the settings in the configuration, I can edit those, I can set the extension as enabled, but except for the settings, it's not working.

Strange thing is that I had no problems on my localhost.

I deleted my cache in Magento and in var/cache, I deleted my sessions, I logged out and loggedin multiple times and still, the extension is not working.

Where do I have to look further? Struggling with it for 5 hours now...
Maybe something with my permissions?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out: Compilation was enabled. I had to disabled it, clear it, recompiled and enabled it again.

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider turning on logging and reviewing the log files for errors. Another idea would be to review network traffic to see if it is even reaching Postcode.nl.

Comment: Can't see anything in my logs. On localhost it is working, so I don't think it the network traffic.